# PHP utf8 preg_replace

Tags: regex, utf-8, preg-replace

In one of the posts here I've found this expression

```
    // Replaces every non-letter, non-digit with a dash
    $str = preg_replace('/(?=\P{Nd})\P{L}/u', '-', $str);
```

It works good but how to keep also basic punctuation signs and spaces ?

I've tried something like this

```
    $str = preg_replace('/(?=\P{Nd})\P{L}\P{P}/u', '-', $str);
```

or

```
    $str = preg_replace('/[^\P{Nd}\P{L}\P{P}$]/u', '-', $str);
```

or

```
    $str = preg_replace('/[\P{Nd}\P{L}\P{P}]/u', '-', $str);
```

and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[^\p{N}\p{L}\p{P}\s]
```

usage:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\p{N}\p{L}\p{P}\s]/u', '-', $str);
```